# optional match is not returning expected results

Tags: neo4j

I have a following query (first one simplified to show the issue)

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (recEmployee:RecordEmployee)-[:Reference{Id:'F08'}]-(recComputer_F08:RecordComputer)-[:Reference{Id:'F09'}]-(recIncidents_F08_F09:RecordIncidents),
(recEmployee:RecordEmployee),
(recEmployee:RecordEmployee)-[:Reference{Id:'F08'}]-(recComputer_F08:RecordComputer) 
WHERE ( recIncidents_F08_F09.F01="Trojan" ) 
RETURN recEmployee
```

it doesn't return anything.
if I remove third optional match, then it works fine. Is it a bug? I was thinking means just that optional.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (recEmployee:RecordEmployee)-[:Reference{Id:'F08'}]-(recComputer_F08:RecordComputer)-[:Reference{Id:'F09'}]-(recIncidents_F08_F09:RecordIncidents),
(recEmployee:RecordEmployee)
WHERE ( recIncidents_F08_F09.F01="Trojan" ) 
RETURN recEmployee
```

Ok, I didn't want to confuse the issue, but of course people start to talk about duplicate path and what not. I thought the fact that optional matches don't return anything is a bug and maybe somebody has workaround. Here is a full query that returns nothing when it should return 2 nodes.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (recEmployee:RecordEmployee)-[:Reference{Id:'F08'}]-(recComputer_F08:RecordComputer)-[:Reference{Id:'F09'}]-(recIncidents_F08_F09:RecordIncidents),
(recEmployee:RecordEmployee),
(recEmployee:RecordEmployee)-[:Reference{Id:'F08'}]-(recComputer_F08:RecordComputer) 
WHERE ( recIncidents_F08_F09.F01="Trojan" ) OR (recComputer_F08.F02="WSMYSTATION")
RETURN recEmployee
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to write the optional query (the second one)

`OPTIONAL MATCH (recEmployee:RecordEmployee)-[:Reference{Id:'F08'}]-(recComputer_F08:RecordComputer)-[:Reference{Id:'F09'}]-(recIncidents_F08_F09:RecordIncidents)
WHERE ( recIncidents_F08_F09.F01="Trojan" ) 
RETURN recEmployee
union
OPTIONAL MATCH (recEmployee:RecordEmployee)-[:Reference{Id:'F08'}]-(recComputer_F08:RecordComputer) 
WHERE (recComputer_F08.F02="WS-MRSPFRY02")`

Unfortunately different paths with OR only possible with union after long research.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

This is not a bug. The behavior results from 2 factors:

- A single `MATCH` or `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause will filter out duplicate relationships, and
- Your `OPTIONAL MATCH` has multiple patterns that contain the same exact sub-pattern involving a relationship between 2 specific nodes.

The sub-pattern `(recEmployee:RecordEmployee)-[:Reference{Id:'F08'}]-(recComputer_F08:RecordComputer)` is repeated in 2 patterns within a single `OPTIONAL MATCH`. Since any `Reference` relationship found by the first instance of the pattern will also be found by the second instance, neo4j will filter out all result rows. This is why your first query gets no results.

You need to avoid repeating the same sub-pattern (involving the same relationship type between the same 2 nodes) within multiple patterns in the same `MATCH` or `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause.

Comment: 1. I cannot, this is simplified query full query have an or clause that looks for computer name. So both optional path should be there.
2. Removing duplicates doesn't explain removal of all. In which circumstance distinct(1,1) returns null?

Comment: 1. Why do you have to repeat the same exact sub-pattern in the same query? 2. I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: I added the query to original post, it explains it. It's on the bottom.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the `WHERE` clause. The issue is with the  `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause, which is unchanged in the query you just added to the bottom.

Comment: I have edited my answer to, hopefully, make the issue more clear.

Comment: Do you have a solution to get result with an OR statement? Otherwise confirming that there is a problem with optional match is not really an answer. I tried changing aliases to fool the server, but then if you have all aliases changed you get unholy matrix of very same employee records named differently (works good for nodes, but for field retrieval it's a mess), or if you change just one alias, not returning correct results at all.

Comment: Your question was: "Is it a bug?" I answered that. If you have another question, you should create a new question.

Comment: The question was "optional match is not returning expected results" implying that I am interested to get expected results. As far as your understanding of question of "is it a bug", I still don't know the answer to that one either. Since the query doesn't work I assume it is? I will wait a day or two to see if somebody can provide a helpful answer to the problem. If not and Neo4j doesn't acknowledge it's a bug. I will mark yours as answer.

Comment: It is not a bug. It is working as designed. The `MATCH` clause filters out duplicates.